# New Dell 3437 preinstalled Ubuntu laptop not working

Tags: 12.04, dell, inspiron

I got a new Dell 3437 laptop, when ONed the laptop ubuntu started to install intself. But at the end some packages didn't installed properly like "Update Manager". After that I am not able to update or upgrade and the laptop came with 12.04 version. Meanwhile the wireless driver got updated, now I am not able to use Wifi also. I tried to reboot the system and install again, but it is not working or I don't know how to do it.

I checked with Dell Support they are not understanding, the support guy told to install Windows, then they will help, I told I dont't want windows and purposefully taken Ubuntu the guy didn't understand at all.

Now I planned to download a ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS and then install again in the laptop.

What is the suggestion. This is a brand new Laptop bought yesterday only.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the `bt-dw1705-firmware` package was used for but removing it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 is quite old enough ..there is ubuntu 16.04 out on Ubuntu's official site..i dont know if they have removed support of 12.04 ..if they have then yes some packages wont download on your system and they wont install... better u get iso file from official site make it bootable and reinstall latest LTS version that will install everything on your Ubuntu pc :)

Comment: Btw u can activate wifi driver again ..select driver manager from app drawer , in additional driver tab select use bcmwl-wireless....driver...and apply settings... hope this helps